# Run command as user does not work as expected in a particular case

Tags: dconf

As a normal user

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ icon-size 24'
```

and

```
gsettings get org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ icon-size 24'
```

are both fine.

As root:

```
su - oem -c 'gsettings get org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ icon-size 24'
```

is okay, but

```
su - oem -c 'gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ icon-size 24'
```

gives no error but does not change the Value

Comment: get is not meant to change the value. Also, http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly

Answer (score 2):

I see no issue, `get` is not meant to change the value.

Get is meant to get the current value, not change anything.